Is constructing a list from a list guaranteed to make a copy?
I have some python code that takes an iterable (list or tuple or generator expression or any other iterable), and needs to copy it into a new list.
The following works:
newlist = [x for x in olditerable]

But I'm wondering whether I can just do this instead:
newlist = list(olditerable)

Obviously it works as required (makes a copy) if olditerable is not a list.
Less-obviously, it also seems to work as required (makes a copy) when olditerable is a list:
oldlist = [1,2,3]
newlist = list(oldlist)
assert newlist is not oldlist  # so it didn't just return oldlist
oldlist.append("appended to oldlist")
newlist.append("appended to newlist")
print(f"oldlist is {oldlist}")
print(f"newlist is {newlist}")

The output further confirms that newlist is not oldlist:
oldlist is [1, 2, 3, 'appended to oldlist']
newlist is [1, 2, 3, 'appended to newlist']

Is this copying behavior guaranteed?  I haven't been able to find any documentation about it one way or another.
In contrast, tuple(oldtuple) does not make a copy (of course, since it would be silly to, since tuples are immutable):
oldtuple = (1,2,3)
newtuple = tuple(oldtuple)
assert newtuple is oldtuple


The behaviour of list() and tuple() is identical. Both operations create a shallow copy. They just transfer the contents to a different type of container. Thus: a = [[0]]; b = list(a); c = tuple(a); c[0] is b[0] is a[0] => True. All of the various methods for making shallow copies of both lists and tuples behave in the same way (e.g. b[:][0] is c[:][0] => True). The mutability of the container is irrelevant.

@ekhumoro Except if you call tuple(...) on a tuple, it doesn't need to make a copy at all; it can return the same tuple passed in.

@khelwood That's true - the opening sentence of my comment doesn't make it clear that I was only talking about copying of the contents. The documentation of list() vs tuple() is literally identical in this regard - it's only the copying of the container that differs. I'm not sure why the OP wasn't able to find this. Or perhaps they did, but they're just unsure what the docs mean by "copy".

@ekhumoro "I'm not sure why the OP wasn't able to find this" - I just wasn't succeeding in finding it via web search. I had been trying searches like "python list constructor" to no avail. Once the doc is found, it's clear to me.

From the list() docs:

The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same
order as iterable’s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a
container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable
is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to
iterable[:]. For example, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and
list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, the
constructor creates a new empty list, [].

What the docs don't make clear here is that the type constructor list() performs a shallow copy. This means that while the list object itself is new, its elements are not copied but instead referenced. If your list contains mutable objects (like other lists or dictionaries), modifications to those objects inside the new list will affect the original list:
>>> oldlist = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> newlist = list(oldlist)
>>> newlist[1].append(5)
>>> oldlist
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> newlist
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> newlist.append(6)
>>> oldlist
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> newlist
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], 6]

If you want a deep copy you can use the aptly named copy.deepcopy function:
>>> import copy
>>> oldlist = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> newlist = copy.deepcopy(oldlist)
>>> newlist[1].append(5)
>>> oldlist
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> newlist
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

